# How use method 'truncate' in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pg-search

```
 class SearchingController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  def index
    @masters = User.search_by_full_name(params[:full_name]).where(master: :true)
    @courses = Course.searching_courses(params[:course_title])
    @masters = truncate(@masters, separator: '[')
  end

end
```

This is my controller. He return error

> undefined method `truncate' for ActiveRecord::Relation []

how resolve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncate works for Strings, but you call it with an ActiveRecord::Relation. First you have to call `.first` on `@masters` (or something similar to select just one record) and then a String attribute like `.full_name`

```
@masters = truncate(
  User.search_by_full_name(params[:full_name]).where(master: :true)
    .first.full_name
  , separator: '['
)
```

You can also call it on each record:

```
@masters = User.search_by_full_name(params[:full_name]).where(master: :true)
  .map { |master|
    truncate(master.full_name, separator: '[')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to apply the truncate method to an array, which won't work because truncate only works with strings.

You're issue really lies within the `@masters` property. You need to deduce it into whatever string you're trying to truncate.

Answer (score 1):

The truncate method from ActionView::Helpers only works on strings.

@masters is an active record relational object, so the method won't work.

Comment: I am curious, what do you want to accomplish with the method? There may be some better options and you could convert the Relation object's attributes to strings

Comment: it is very difficult to explain in a foreign language